# What is the name of the crossover genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

The genetic algorithm which has

```
 'parent1 1111|0101
  parent2 0000|1010

  offspring 11110000'
```

comes under which kind of crossover genetic algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the first half of parent 1 and parent 2 are combined. I believe that's called single point crossover.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury I would say that the offspring comes from the repeated application of the *two-point crossover*

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of different ones, you have to specify more examples. To me it looks like a varation of a *single point crossover*. In the first 4 bits, the bits of parent1 are taken.

In the next 4 bits, we have either of the following (logical) options:

- AND (the offspring will only have a 1 if both parents have 1)
- UNIFORM (the offspring takes a bit randomly from their parents, so it took 4 0's randomly)

But it is hard to say. The first part could also have been UNIFORM for example You need to specify more test cases for us to accurately given an answer.

Comment: it takes first part from parent 1 and also first part from parent 2